# Error while performing multiclass classification using Gridsearch CV

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, multi-class

I am trying to solve a multiclass classification problem using SVC as the base estimator and GridSearchCV to tune my results. Mentioned below is the code and the error being received:

```
svc_clf = SVC(C=0.7,tol=0.01,kernel='rbf',cache_size=500)
param_grid = {'C':np.linspace(0.1,1.0,10),'tol':[1e-7,1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1],'kernel':['rbf','poly'],'degree':[3,4,5,6,7]}

gs_svc = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc_clf,param_grid=param_grid,scoring='f1',cv=5)

gs_svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Below is the error received:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.
```

Upon my research I found that 'f1-score' isn't for multi-class classification.
Please suggest which metric should be used for GridSearchCV for a multi-class classification problem ?

Comment: just use different scoring e.g. `scoring='accuracy'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accuracy might look tempting but not a good metric in general. In multilabel classification, for each class we'll have `f1` score, `precision`, `recall` values etc. You need to decide how to average them, which is what the error is saying actually. The [options](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) are `binary` (which is the default one), `micro`, `macro`, `weighted`, `samples`. `binary` option needs positive and negative classes, and doesn't work in multilabel problems.

To reiterate `sklearn` documentation linked above, `micro` option calculates `TP,FP` etc. globally, while `macro` does it specific to each class and averages them. `weighted` is the weighted version of `macro` average
that accounts for class imbalance.

And, this parameter needs to be passed into the scorer function, e.g.:

```
scorer = sklearn.metrics.make_scorer(sklearn.metrics.f1_score, average = 'weighted')
gs_svc = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc_clf,param_grid=param_grid,scoring=scorer,cv=5)
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [gunes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/204068/gunes)' excellent answer, you may also use several scoring functions:

```
scoring = {'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score),
           'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average = 'macro'),
           'recall': make_scorer(recall_score, average = 'macro'),
           'f1_macro': make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'macro',
           'f1_weighted': make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'weighted')}

gs_svc = GridSearchCV(estimator=svc_clf,param_grid=param_grid,scoring=scoring,cv=5)
gs_svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: just to add info, this is pretty useful and works with `GridSearchCV` and  `RandomSearchCV`. Though, you can´t do this if you are using `BayesSearchCV` - this was quite surprising, considering they all "follow the same interface" and belong to sklearn